# Refresh Token HTTPInterceptor issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I have been stuck on this for a while now. For some reason, my Interceptor refreshes the token (and even calls the endpoints that failed while attempting the refresh); however, my models do not update until I create another request.

Below is my HTTPInterceptor code:

```
private refreshTokenInProgress = false;
private tokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
constructor(private auth: AuthService, private http: HttpClient) { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Rewrite API url/content-type depending on environment (rewrite only ONCE)
    request = request.clone({
        url: environment.apiUrl + request.url,
        setHeaders: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }
    });

    request = this.generateAuthHeaders(request);
    return next.handle(request).catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // Make sure we only attempt to refresh when we have an access token
        if (error.status === 401 && this.auth.getAccessToken()) {
            // If we are currently awaiting a token refresh, don't attempt to refresh
            if (!this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
                this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;
                this.tokenSubject.next(null);

                // Attempt to refresh tokens
                return this.auth.refreshToken().switchMap((result: any) => {
                        // Set new tokens if result, otherwise, logout
                        if (result) {
                            this.auth.setAccessToken(result.accessToken);
                            this.auth.setRefreshToken(result.refreshToken);
                            this.tokenSubject.next(result);
                            this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
                            return next.handle(this.generateAuthHeaders(request));
                        }
                        this.auth.logout();
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                        // Error while attempting to refresh our tokens, logout
                        if (err.status === 401) {
                            this.auth.logout();
                        }
                        return Observable.throw(err);
                    });
            } else {
                return this.tokenSubject.filter((result) => result !== null).take(1).switchMap((result) => {
                    return next.handle(this.generateAuthHeaders(request));
                });
            }
        }
        return Observable.throw(error);
    });
}

generateAuthHeaders(request: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> {
    // If we are authenticated, send Authentication header
    const accessToken = this.auth.getAccessToken();
    if (accessToken) {
        return request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
            }
        });
    }
    return request;
}
```

As well as the code involved with the following images:

```
setPage(pageInfo) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.usersService.getUsers(pageInfo.offset, pageInfo.limit).subscribe((pagination) => {
        this.pagination = pagination;
        this.rows = pagination.docs;
        this.loading = false; // None of these get called
    }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.loading = false; // None of these get called
    });
}
```

[image]

As you can see it seems to be working, however `loading` never gets set to false which means it isn't working properly.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to update automatically. FYI you're ruining your tooling by specifying all those `any`s let the compiler do its job and infer the type